# Synchronize Gradle and Android Studio Versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android studio was taking up a massive amount of disk space on my computer (over 50 GB) and my old 90 GB ssd was completely full. I tried to reduce the amount of space that was being used by completely removing everything from android studio except my project and then reinstalling it.

There were some problems that I worked through, such as updating the sdk version, but I am stuck on this error message:

```
Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)
```

I tried disabling instant run, but it did not fix the problem, and I like instant run anyway.

I also tried installing a new version of gradle and then pointing to it in settings/buildtools/gradle, and I've also tried checking the box to use the default wrapper instead.

I tried modifying my class path in build.gradle when I changed to gradle 3.0 in the settings above:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
```

My android studio is version 2.1.3/143.3101438

How do I get the right version of gradle installed and update my project to use it?

Comment: Gradle is independent of Android Studio and the Android plugin for Gradle. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: The android plugin for gradle. Whatever I use to compile my android code and stuff it in my handheld computer.

Comment: I see. Does this post answer your questions?  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. I had to specify the version of gradle in three places. First in settings/buildtools/gradle set it to use the default wrapper. Second specify the gradle version in build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

Third, in gradle.wrapper.properties specify the gradle version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

(I originally set it to ...gradle-2.13-all.zip, but it changed it to 2.14.1 after i put in 2.13, but it did not update the version in the build.gradle file)

I'm still very much confused what gradle is doing, why I need to specify the version 3 times, but at least it works.

Comment: The latest Gradle version is 3.0, I believe. And like I said in the comments, Gradle is independent of Android Studio - it can build many other types of projects.

Comment: And if you want to save disk space, replace `all` with `bin` in the properties file